# House electric arrangement mystery

Tags: electrical

I have two devices that started to work constantly. That is I can't turn them off. They just run all the time. The switches don't do anything.

The two devices are the the ventilator and air-exchanger in the bathroom:

[image]
[image]

And there are two twiches that control them (respectively):

[image]
[image]

Now to the amazing part.

When you switch off the circuit break for the ventilator in the ceiling (the circuit break for the on/off switch), then the ventilator stop running but the air-exchanger still continues to run.

**When you turn off the circuit break for the air-exchanger, the air exchanger stops running and the ventilator in the bathroom is now controllable with the on/off switch**.

So my conclusion is that the controller for the air-exchanger is broken. And that the air-exchanger is hooked up to the bathroom-fan to control it too.

What bothers me is that why the fan stops when I turn off the break for the on/off switch? I mean if we agree that the air-exchanger has control over the fan too, why disconnecting the on/off switch stops the ventilator?

When the circuit-break for the air-exchanger is off, the ventilator is controller by the simple on/off switch.

```
| CB air-ex | CB vent | Swch Vent  || Vent  | Air-ex |
| ON        | ON      | ON         || ON    | ON     |
| ON        | ON      | OFF        || ON    | ON     |
```

That's ^ obvious. As I said the devices run constantly. **The "switch" for the air-ex never does anything at all. It's not even included in the table.**

```
| CB air-ex | CB vent | Swch Vent  || Vent  | Air-ex |
| OFF       | ON      | ON         || ON    | OFF    |
| OFF       | ON      | OFF        || OFF   | OFF    |
```

When the `CB air-ex` is off, the control comes back to the on/off switch. So now you think that the "priority" controls is the air-exchange. Okay. See this:

```
| CB air-ex | CB vent | Swch Vent  || Vent  | Air-ex |
| ON        | OFF     | ON         || OFF   | ON     |
| ON        | OFF     | OFF        || OFF   | ON     |
```

If you turn off the CB to the ON/OFF switch, the ventilator is off.

**So why, when the `CB vent` is off the vent is off, but when the on/off switch is off, the vent is on?**

Thanks kindly in advance for your thoughts and comments.

P.S. This started after the house got hit by lightening.

Comment: Before the house was struck by lightning, did the ventilator and air-exchanger operate completely independently from each other, or was there some interaction between their controls?

Answer (score 1):

Turn off the breaker for the 3 switches and remove the cover and see if the wiring is burnt. The switch is likely shorted in the on position so only cutting power at the breaker will de-energize the circuit. And since switches are controlling the wrong things but in the same switch box there is likely wiring fused together somewhere. Follow your nose

Comment: The question is: why cutting the break for the on/off switch stops the fan when there is also control coming from the air-exchanger?
At the same time, putting the on/off switch to off has no effect when the air-exchanger is running.
That's what is bothering me.

Comment: I mean, I agree. Ofcourse something got fused together.
But I want to understand why the on/off switch doesn't affect the ventilator but switching off the break for the on off switch stops the ventilator. That's weird to me.

Comment: Are they wired in series?

Comment: It gets its power source before the switch. So it's always hot.  Only thing  I can think of at the moment

Comment: Ground before the switch is what I meant. Sorry

Comment: Since the switch completes the circuit when on I think it's being bypassed and always on

Comment: If the switch is bypassed, why turning off it's circuit break stops the fan? Is it not bypassed?

Comment: If power for the switch has a ground prior to the switch then the switch is useless. Killing power at the breaker kills the circuit not the switch if it's been bypassed.